# Combination of $n$ letter out of $3n$.

Tags: combinatorics

> Show that the number of combinations of $n$ letters out of $3n$ letters of which $n$ are $a$s , $n$ are $b$s and the rest are unequal is $(n+2)2^{n-1}$.

### My approach...

The number of ways of distributing $n$ distict object in $k$ distinct box is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ now when $k=2$ the logic stands as $\binom{n+2-1}{2-1}$=$\binom{n+1}{1}$.

Selection of $j$ distinct letter out of $n$ is $\binom{n}{j}$.

Hence my answer will be $\sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{j+1}{1}\binom{n}{n-j}$.

Please help me with the answer

Comment: Not sure I am following.  How many letters are there in total?  Suppose $n=1$...can you list all the combinations you have in mind?

Comment: I copied the question in toto, there are 3n letters, n a's n b's and n distinct we have to select n letters

Comment: I asked for an example.  If $n=1$ please list all the combinations.  There are only meant to be $(1+2)\times 2^0=3$ of them...what are they?

Comment: Oh, you are saying that, with $n=1$, there are $3$ letters and you want to choose one of those?  So that's $a,b,x$ in that case.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct for n=1 it is 3 {a},{b} or {any one letter among n distinct letter}

Comment: So, first choose a subset of size $i$ from the distinct ones ($\binom ni$ ways to do it).  That leaves you $n-i$ to choose.  Your selection is determined by how many $a's$ you pick so there are $n-i+1$ ways to pick the rest.

Comment: @lulu: but it seems to understand that the other characters are $c,d,e, ...$ and not a different, but same, character $x$.

Comment: @GCab I think what Lulu meant was that you partition the letters into three sets (the $a$'s, the $b$'s and a third set of $\{c,d,e,\ldots\}$). Then pick subsets of $i$ elements from the $\{c,d,e,\ldots\}$ set and see how many $a$'s and $b$'s you need to append to it. Frankly, I can understand this method but not yours or the OP's

Comment: @GCab  Not sure what you are saying.  I am assuming that the other $n$ characters are all distinct from one another and distinct from $a,b$.  The OP could clarify if that is wrong.

Comment: @Jam: In the first part of my answer I was not giving for sure that the "proposed" result was actually the "correct" result. I added a second part for that. My comment to *Lulu* was about the ways of choosing the "remaining" letters, for which order should (?) be accounted for, and thus $n(n-1)\cdots(n-i+1)$ and not ${n \choose i}$.

Comment: @lulu: see my comment above: actually the OP did not fully specify the construction rules of the words to be considered.

Comment: @GCab  I agree the rules are unspecified and unclear.  The OP should clarify.

Comment: @lulu: since no clarification has come yet, then I re-elaborated my answer under 2 different interpretations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The required number is coefficient of $x^n$ in $$[(1+x+x^2+\cdots x^n)^2(1+x)^n].$$

Do some simplification and find that the coefficient of $x^n$ is $$2^n\binom {n+2-1}{1} - \binom n1 2^{n-1} \binom{n+1-1}{0} = (n+2)2^{n-1}$$

Comment: I got the answer by using $x(1+x)^{n}$ by differentiating it and putting x=1 .I appreciate the stack user team's dedication in taking painstaking effort to solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

Your answer gives the  proposed result
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left( \matrix{
  j + 1 \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  n - j \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left( \matrix{
  j \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  n - j \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left( \matrix{
  j \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  n - j \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left( \matrix{
  j \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  j - 1 \cr}  \right)}  + 2^{\,n}  =   \cr 
  &  = n\,2^{\,n - 1}  + 2^{\,n}  = \left( {n + 2} \right)2^{\,n - 1}  \cr} 
$$
where to obtain the last sum the *"Trinomial Revision"* has been applied
$$
\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  m \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  q \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  q \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n - q \cr 
  m - q \cr}  \right)
$$

This results in $$ 1,3,8,20,48, \cdots$$

The above is the result when "combinations" means
*number of sub-multisets of cardinality $n$ from the multiset $\{a \times n,\; b \times n,\; 1,\, 2,\, \cdots,n\}$*
as explicitated by the z-Transform provided in previous answer.
That means that the order of the characters is not taken into account.

If instead "combinations" means
*number of words of length $n$ from the alphabet $\{a \times n,\; b \times n,\; 1,\, 2,\, \cdots,n\}$*
then the order of the characters is taken into account.

In this case, we have that $k$ numeric characters can be choosen 
in ${n^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } =n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$ ways.
In the remaining places we have a binary subword of length $n-k$.

Then the number of words will be
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } 2^{\,n - k} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{{n!} \over {\left( {n - k} \right)!}}2^{\,n - k} }  = n!\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{{2^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\,2} n!Q\left( {n,2} \right) \cr} 
$$
$Q$ being the Regularized Incomplete Gamma function.

This returns
$$
1,3,10,38,168, \cdots 
$$