# Problem on binomial coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Prove that:
> $$\binom{n}0\binom{n+1}n+\binom n1\binom n{n-1}+\cdots+\binom nn\binom 10=2^{n-1}(n+2)$$

[image]

**what i observed:**

The sum of the lower indices in all the terms is a constant values $n$. Also the value of the sum of the upper indices in each term is decreasing by 1 and goes from $2n+1$ to $n+1$ at the end.

However i am unable to solve the problem. How do i start the problem, any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your graphic is difficult for me to read.  I ask that you replace it by editing your query, using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to display math.  Also, a minor point:  personally, I am more accustomed to seeing `$\binom{n}{k}$` : $\binom{n}{k}$ to represent $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$

Comment: $\binom{k+1}k$ has a nice closed formula.

Comment: Once we make a fairly straightforward change of variable in the combinations, this comes out to be the same question as in  the post [Combination of $n$ letter out of $3n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481407/combination-of-n-letter-out-of-3n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal{\text{Hint:}} $

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} \binom{n+1-r}{n-r} = \sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr(n+1-r) = (n+1)\sum_{r=0}^n \binom nr -\sum_{r=0}^n r\binom nr$$

The second sum may be evaluated easily because $$r\binom nr=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}  $$ for $r\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard notation $C^n_k=\binom{n}{k}$ your identity looks like
$$\sum _{i = 0}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{n+1-i}{n-i}=\sum _{i = 0}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{n+1-i}{1}=\sum _{i = 0}^n\binom{n}{i}(n+1-i).$$
**Hint:** Use the binomial theorem for the first part and for the second one you need to know what is $\sum _{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}\cdot k$. I suggest you write $k$ as $\binom{k}{1}$ and show that $\dbinom{a}{b}\dbinom{b}{c}=\dbinom{a}{c}\dbinom{a-c}{b-c}.$

Comment: Too bad, this question was already asked and answered.  Please search for duplicates, ***prior to answering***, as per the EoQS.

Comment: @amWhy mmmm ok.